# Capture VBS objshell.Run error

Tags: vbscript, sqlcmd

I have the below bit of VBS which calls, and runs, a *.sql query via SQLCMD.

How can I improve the error checking? If I delete the *.sql file it thinks it has completed successfully even though it can't have had.

```
Writelog "Attempting to run *.sql"
err = objshell.Run ("cmd /c sqlcmd -U sa -P Password -i c:\temp\abc.sql",1,FALSE)
If err <> 0 Then
    WriteLog "Error running SQL = " & err & "(" & err.description & ")"
Else
    WriteLog "Successfully run SQL"
End If
```

Comment: Read help _bWaitOnReturn 
Optional. Boolean value indicating whether the script should wait for the program to finish executing before continuing to the next statement in your script. If set to true, script execution halts until the program finishes, and Run returns any error code returned by the program. If set to false (the default), the Run method returns immediately after starting the program, automatically returning 0 (not to be interpreted as an error code)._

Comment: Perfect - many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Noodles pointed out in the comments to your question you need to set the third parameter of the [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method (`bWaitOnReturn`) to `True` so that your VBScript waits for the external command to complete.

However, that alone doesn't suffice. You also need to run [`sqlcmd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) with the additional parameter `-b` to make it return a non-zero exit code in case of an error:

> **`-b`**
>
> Specifies that `sqlcmd` exits and returns a DOS ERRORLEVEL value when an error occurs. The value that is returned to the DOS ERRORLEVEL variable is 
>   **1** when the SQL Server error message has a severity level greater than 10; otherwise, the value returned is **0**. If the `-V` option has been set in addition to `-b`, `sqlcmd` will not report an error if the severity level is lower than the values set using `-V`. Command prompt batch files can test the value of ERRORLEVEL and handle the error appropriately. sqlcmd does not report errors for severity level 10 (informational messages).
>
> If the `sqlcmd` script contains an incorrect comment, syntax error, or is missing a scripting variable, ERRORLEVEL returned is 1.

And you don't need `cmd /c`, because your external command does not use any CMD builtin features (like internal commands, pipeline, or redirection).

Also, do not use `err` as a variable name. VBScript has an intrinsic global object [`Err`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf5ze0e%28v=vs.84%29) for providing runtime error information, which is automatically populated when a runtime error occurs. Trying to assign a value to it should raise an error by itself.

Change your code to something like this:

```
rc = objshell.Run("sqlcmd -b -U sa -P Password -i c:\temp\abc.sql", 1, True)
If rc <> 0 Then
    WriteLog "Error running SQL = " & rc
Else
    WriteLog "Successfully run SQL"
End If
```